# While loop output on the same line

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP loop where i output some stuff from my database to my page but i have a problem, when runing the code it ends up on different lines like example 1 When i want it to be on the came line line example 2, i have tried usiv div, floating the container and using CSS to make it inline but it just end up like example 1 all the time, why?

Example 1:
1
2
3
4
5

Examle 2:
1,2,3,4,5

```
<?php

$getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dogs ORDER by ID LIMIT 5");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))

{
    $id=$rows['id'];

    echo '<br>';
    echo '<div id="block" border="1" width="200" style="float:center">';
echo '
    <a href="mypage.com/index.php?dog=', $id, '">
        <img src="/thumb/', $id, '.jpg" alt="dogs!" />
    </a>';
    echo '</div>';

}

?>
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql`, use `mysqli` and [bind your in- / output](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/proper-easy-mysqli-php/)

Comment: `mysql_*` is **deprecated**. Please look at `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the issue? I can't see what the problem is from your question.

Comment: remove the echo '<br>';

Comment: Why do you put ` /` at the end of `<img>` tag, but not to `<br>` ? Remember: `<br>` = HTML4 and HTML5, `<br />` = XHTML4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take line break out of the loop. Each time there is a result, you print `<br>` that's why it's on new line

```
echo '<br />';
echo '<div id="block" border="1" width="200" style="float:center">';

$getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dogs ORDER by ID LIMIT 5");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)){
    $id=$rows['id'];
    echo '<a href="mypage.com/index.php?dog='. $id .'">
        <img src="/thumb/'. $id .'.jpg" alt="dogs!" />
    </a>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

and yes to the comments - please look into using **mysqli**

---

with counter:

```
echo '<div id="block" border="1" width="200" style="float:center">';
$i = 0;
$getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dogs ORDER by ID LIMIT 5");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)){

    $id=$rows['id'];
    echo '<a href="mypage.com/index.php?dog='. $id .'">
        <img src="/thumb/'. $id .'.jpg" alt="dogs!" />
    </a>';

    $i++;
    if($i == 5) {
        echo '<br />';
        $i = 0;
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks you so very much! :)
One more question on the subject, if i wanted to make it 5 on each line or maybe more on each line but each line should always have the same ammount of outputs, how would i do this ?

Comment: @user2406918 use a counter $i++; inside your while loop and check when it equals i.e. 5, echo `<br />` and reset counter to `0`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your concatenation is wrong.

```
<a href="mypage.com/index.php?dog='. $id . '">
<img src="/thumb/'. $id . '.jpg" alt="dogs!" />
```